# Cómo reemplazar valores en dos DataFrame independientes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo los siguientes dos `DataFrame` con una columna con el mismo nombre `iden`:

```
df1: 
iden   c    A1   A2    A3    
 11     1     1     1   NaN
 23     2     3     3   NaN
 11     3     2     2     1
 74     4   NaN     1   NaN
 74     1   NaN   NaN   NaN

df2= 
iden caso    
74     A
77     B
11     C
25     A
48     B
```

Lo que necesito es reemplazar todos los valores de la columna `iden`en los dos `DataFrame` de tal manera que si hay un valor que esta en los dos `DataFrame` se asigne el mismo número, los valores son identificadores. En el ejemplo la respuesta sería:

```
df1: 
    iden   c    A1   A2    A3    
     1     1     1     1   NaN
     2     2     3     3   NaN
     1     3     2     2     1
     3     4   NaN     1   NaN
     3     1   NaN   NaN   NaN

    df2= 
    iden caso    
    3     A
    4     B
    1     C
    5     A
    6     B
```

Pense en crear una nueva columna en cada DataFrame usando `isin` para la generación del número:

```
df1['new_iden'] = list(".." if x else ".." for x in df1.iden.isin(df2.iden))
```

y luego borrar la columna original.

Pero no se como decirle que valor colocarle al if para que vaya generando los números como se requiera.

Agradezco en lo que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Puedes compartir el código de lo que has intentado por lo menos?

Comment: Gracias por su mensaje, ya actualice con lo que tengo, la verdad no se como continuar, como lograr esa relación entre los df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posibilidad es iterar sobre ambas columnas (primero `df1.iden` y luego `df2.iden`) e ir asignando nuevos valores en ese orden, usando un diccionario como intermediario para almacenar las parejas **`"antiguo valor": "nuevo valor"`**. Después basta con hacer uso de `loc`/`at` y asignar a cada celda su nuevo valor de acuerdo al diccionario:

```
import io
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""\
iden   c    A1   A2    A3    
 11     1     1     1   NaN
 23     2     3     3   NaN
 11     3     2     2     1
 74     4   NaN     1   NaN
 74     1   NaN   NaN   NaN
 """), sep="\s+"
 )

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""\
iden caso    
74     A
77     B
11     C
25     A
48     B
"""), sep="\s+"
)

new_ids = {}
num = 1
for idx1, id1 in df1.iden.iteritems():
    if (new_id1 := new_ids.get(id1)) is None:
        new_id1 = new_ids[id1] = num
        num += 1
    df1.at[idx1, "iden"] = new_id1

for idx2, id2 in df2.iden.iteritems():
    if (new_id2 := new_ids.get(id2)) is None:
        new_id2 = new_ids[id2] = num
        num += 1
    df2.at[idx2, "iden"] = new_id2
```

**Salida:**

> ```
> >>> df1
>
>    iden  c   A1   A2   A3
> 0     1  1  1.0  1.0  NaN
> 1     2  2  3.0  3.0  NaN
> 2     1  3  2.0  2.0  1.0
> 3     3  4  NaN  1.0  NaN
> 4     3  1  NaN  NaN  NaN
>
> >>> df2
>
>    iden caso
> 0     3    A
> 1     4    B
> 2     1    C
> 3     5    A
> 4     6    B
> ```

---

Si se usa **Python < 3.8.x** (sin [expresiones de asignación](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)) el código debería ser:

```
new_ids = {}
num = 1
for idx1, id1 in df1.iden.iteritems():
    new_id1 = new_ids.get(id1)
    if new_id1 is None:
        new_id1 = new_ids[id1] = num
        num += 1
    df1.at[idx1, "iden"] = new_id1

for idx2, id2 in df2.iden.iteritems():
    new_id2 = new_ids.get(id2)
    if new_id2 is None:
        new_id2 = new_ids[id2] = num
        num += 1
    df2.at[idx2, "iden"] = new_id2
```

Existen como siempre más posibilidades, otra opción es hacer uso de `collectiosn.defaultdict` para generar el diccionario junto a `itertools.count` (como generador de las nuevas claves) y `pandas.Series.replace` para substituir los valores en base al diccionario:

```
import itertools
import collections

ngen = itertools.count(1)
new_ids = collections.defaultdict(lambda: next(ngen))

for idn in itertools.chain(df1.iden, df2.iden):
    new_ids[idn]

df1.iden.replace(new_ids, inplace=True)
df2.iden.replace(new_ids, inplace=True)
```

Para DataFrames con un número relativamente grande de filas y reemplazos es en principio más eficiente que la versión anterior:

> **Nota:** el uso de `io.StringIO` y `pandas.read_csv` es solo para hacer el código reproducible tomando como base el ejemplo de la pregunta.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

puedes crear una función que genere números sucesivos en cada iteración:

```
def auto_increment_gen():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1

auto_inc = auto_increment_gen()

df1['new_iden'] = list(next(auto_inc) for x in df1.iden.isin(df2.iden))
```

Pero cuidado porque si intentas evaluar el generador entero iterando sobre él en un bucle for, o usándolo para inicializar otros iteradores como listas o sets, entrarás en un bucle infinito.

Si sabes el rango de índices que necesitas puedes hacerlo más seguro con un bucle for.